# Setting up absolute module resolution in Typescript and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Say I just have my folder structure like this

```
my_project \
    dist \
        index.js
        logger.js
    src \
        index.ts
        logger.ts
    tsconfig.json
```

and in index.ts I want to do something like this

```
import logger from 'src/logger';
```

how would I do it? I tried adding

```
...
basedir: ".",
paths: ["src"]
...
```

to tsconfig. This got it to compile and find the logger module at compile time, but then when I build and everything gets compiled to dist, index.js has `require('src/logger')`. Obviously Node has no idea what src is so this doesn't work. So how could I get this set up so that the built modules have the correct import paths?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're really looking for is relative paths, not absolute.   Have you tried using

`import logger from './logger';`